# Execute r scripts in a ubuntu server using browser?

Tags: r, ubuntu

I am having a R script which generates a bar chart, i will get the data modified often. So i want to upload the data and then run this from a browser and also get the results generated on the browser it self. I have gone through FastRweb but it is pretty old repo. Can any one help me on this.

Thanks,
Ans.

Comment: Can you install [RStudio Server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/) on the server?

Comment: Depending on your needs and available resources: [`shiny`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/), [`opencpu`](https://www.opencpu.org/), or (as neilfws suggested) RStudio Server.

Answer (score 0):

To do this I would recommend that you run Shiny on your own webserver with full control. Here is a nice link how to do this.

https://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/

I have scripts tat run daily and schedule this task by CRON. This is quite easy to do:

I give my scripts rights to read, write and execute with the following command

`sudo chmod 777 /path/script.R`

Here is an example of my CRON task:

`*/30 * * * * /bin/sh /home/markus/script.R > /tmp/listener2.log 2>&`

The script should for example manipulate the data and then store it in the folder of your shiny application, where the shiny application reads the data and renders the expected plot.